# How to fix "Error: Path "/__path__/__name@dasherize@if-flat" does not exist" in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I work on a formation on a starter kit about Angular5 and I am in trouble at the moment of create a new component with this command : "npm run ng generate component component/exemple/user/userThumbnail"

I already try to search if someone had the same issues but was in vain.

Here is my Angular configuration :

- Angular CLI: 1.6.0
- Node: 10.15.3
- Angular: 5.0.0
- @angular/cli: 1.6.0
- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
- @angular-devkit/core: 7.3.8
- @angular-devkit/schematics: 7.3.8
- @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
- @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
- @schematics/angular: 0.1.11
- typescript: 2.4.2
- webpack-concat-plugin: 1.4.2
- webpack-dev-server: 2.9.7
- webpack: 3.10.0

Here is the log of my error :

```
Error: Path "/__path__/__name@dasherize@if-flat__/__name@dasherize__.component.html" does not exist.  
Path "/__path__/__name@dasherize@if-flat__/__name@dasherize__.component.html" does not exist.
```

I just want to create a component without any problems.

Thank for help.

Comment: Why are you running an `ng` command with `npm run`? Try running the command without `npm run`. Like this: `ng generate component component/exemple/user/userThumbnail`

Comment: Hum, I agree that's weird but I just follow the formation. So I tried to do this without the npm run, but I have the same result. I don't really know what's wrong with this command. Thank for the suggestion R. Richards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem with this command :

`npm install @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.45 @angular/cli --save`